# Trying to check if a bool is true in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to code a game in Unity. My plan is to code a script where makes a bool variable true when the player collides with an object and then, another script will check everytime to see if the bool it's true. If it's true then, i will print "Leper Jump". Because of the bool variable being in another script, i need to instantiate it and the code looks completely correct but the console says that on line 17 "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". 
Sorry if this sounds a dumb question but i've been trying to fix this for hours and i haven't found the solution, could you help me please?

Here's the code where i convert a bool to true of the player collides:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeperTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Leper;
    public GameObject trigger;
    public bool IsOnLeper = false;

    void Update()
    {

    }

     private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
         {
                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
                {
                Debug.Log("IsOnLeper comes true");
                IsOnLeper = true;
                }
        }
}
```

Here's the script where i try to check if the bool is true (and the error is here):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeperAI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public LeperTrigger lepertriggerinstance;

    void Start()
    {
        lepertriggerinstance = GameObject.FindWithTag("enemy").GetComponent<LeperTrigger>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(lepertriggerinstance.GetComponent<LeperTrigger>().IsOnLeper == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Leper jump");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (line 17)

Using `if (lepertriggerinstance.IsOnLeper) {...}`  did not change the error.

Comment: Looks like `GameObject.FindWithTag("enemy")` found an `enemy` without a `LeperTrigger`, so it set `lepertriggerinstance` to `null`.

Comment: I have only one enemy in the game :/

Comment: what happens if you do `if (lepertriggerinstance.IsOnLeper) {...}` ?

Comment: same error unfortunately :/

Comment: Is `LeperAI` on the same gameobject as `LeperTrigger`?

Comment: No, it's on the enemy gameobject but if i try to put on the same gameobject it will error again

Comment: Then what's `LeperTrigger` attached to? I assume it's not the player. Anyway, this is aside from the problem at hand. If you do 
`void Start() {
    GameObject[] gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy"); 
    Debug.Log("enemylength: " + gos.Length); 
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        lepertriggerinstance=go.GetComponent<LeperTrigger>();   
        Debug.Log("go lt: " + lepertriggerinstance);
    }
}` in `LeperAI`
and `void Start(){Debug.Log("leperTrigger tag: " + gameObject.tag);}` in  `LeperTrigger`, what gets printed?

Comment: You are setting `leppertiggerinstance` to `GameObject.FindWithTag("enemy").GetComponent<LeperTrigger>()` and then checking if `leppertriggerinstance.GetComponent<LeperTrigger>().IsOnLepper == true`. So you are trying to get a `LeperTrigger` component from a `LeperTrigger`?

Comment: Exactly, i'm trying to check if a bool from another script is true, sorry if i didn't explained well.

Comment: leperTrigger tag: Untagged

Comment: enemylength: 0   , here are the results

Comment: @FRP72 Did you find a solution to this that worked for you?

Comment: No :/  , me and my group colleague are trying a different way to do what we were trying.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `lepertriggerinstance` is already an instanc of `LeperTrigger` so whn trying to get the value of your bool, you should not use

`if(lepertriggerinstance.GetComponent<LeperTrigger>().IsOnLeper == true)`

Instead, use `if(lepertriggerinstance.IsOnLeper == true)`

A second alternative is if you only have one instance of LeperTrigger in your scene, or if the one value can be used for all instances, just make bool IsOnLeper static. That way you can just use `if(LeperTrigger.IsOnLeper)`

Comment: This was already discussed in the comments and isn't a cause for the problem at hand

Comment: Please edit your question according to the discussions in comments so that everyone that reads your question is up to date.

Comment: @mertcanb I've added the relevant info to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be looking for another `LeperTrigger` component on the `LeperTrigger` object you already obtained in `Start()`. I changed line 17 below.

If you're still getting the same error, make sure to check:

- You indeed have an object in the scene with the tag `enemy`
- Your object with the tag `enemy` has a `LeperTrigger` script attached to it.

Lastly, if you instantiate the `enemy` object *after* the scene starts, keep in mind that the `Start()` method of `LeperAI` will not run again, thus leaving the `lepertriggerinstance` object null.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeperAI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public LeperTrigger lepertriggerinstance;

    void Start()
    {
        lepertriggerinstance = GameObject.FindWithTag("enemy").GetComponent<LeperTrigger>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(lepertriggerinstance.IsOnLeper == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Leper jump");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're creating your `LeperTrigger` after the `LeperAI` has already looked for a `LeperTrigger`. I would set things up kind of opposite to how your currently doing things.

I would tag whatever GameObject `LeperAI` is on with **LeperAI** then in `LeperTrigger`, find the `LeperAI` and set the value of its `lepertriggerinstance` to itself:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject.FindWithTag("LeperAI").GetComponent<LeperAI>().lepertriggerinstance = this;
}
```

And then in `LeperAI`, change your if statement like so:

```
public LeperTrigger lepertriggerinstance; 

void Start() 
{
    lepertriggerinstance = null; 
} 

void Update()
{ 
    if( lepertriggerinstance != null && lepertriggerinstance.IsOnLeper )
    {
        Debug.Log("Leper jump");
    } 
}
```

... such that `LeperAI` checks if the `LeperTrigger` instance had been created, and if it has, check its value of `IsOnLeper`.

Answer (score 0):

Look, this is much more simple, I don't know if you found a solution yet, assuming your LeperTrigger script is a component to your Leper game object, I think this might be what you needed:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeperAI : MonoBehaviour
{
     void Update()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("Leper").GetComponent<LeperTrigger>().IsOnLeper == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("LeperJump");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this even further by just using the statement `GameObject.Find("Leper").GetComponent<LeperTrigger>().IsOnLeper`. The `== true` is redundant.